# Deployment automation tools for .NET code

Tags: .net, continuous-deployment

My team at my work place is looking to move into Continuous Deployment and I have been asked to find a tool to help in the process. I am fairly new to this area and don't know much about Continuous Deployment tools. Can someone suggest some tools that I should check out.

1) Our application is .NET
2) Source Control is Team Foundation Server 2010 and we plan to include automated builds using TFS in our process.
3) Tool must integrate with Visual Studio 2013 and Team Foundation Server without hassle
4) Open to commercial tools but preference is given to Open Source software.

Comment: Recommending tools is off-topic for Stack Overflow, but since you mention TFS2010, you might want to [read more about its capabilities in this area](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2011/10/17/automated-build-deploy-test-using-tfs-2010/) before you look further.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Asking for tools are considered off-top of this site. You read up on what questions can be asked in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)